# How to select mysql with and or in one single sql statment

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select All Record from my table where referal = 0 and 1 and pos_left=NULL OR pos_right=NULL

Can anyone help me provide sql please.
[Table Record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbESV.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * from your_table 
WHERE referral IN (0,1) 
AND ( ( pos_left IS NULL ) OR ( pos_right IS NULL ) )
```

Problem with logical expressions: field referal cannot be = 0 and 1, like human being is always man OR woman and cannot be man AND woman ;-)